# How can I distinguish current operating system in my .vimrc?

Tags: windows, macos, vim

I use Vim on both OS X and Windows, with almost identical configuration.

I would like to be able to use the same `.vimrc` on the two operating systems, but there are a couple of things I need to configure differently.

What I'd like to add to my `.vimrc` file is:

```
:if <windows>
  "some windows-specific settings here
:elseif <os x>
  "some os x-specific settings here
:endif
```

But I don't know what to use for `<windows>` and `<os x>`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<sub>N.B. Although both previous answers gave me enough information to figure out how to solve the problem (and received upvotes from me), neither actually gave the full answer. So that others with the same question don't have to do the research, I'm adding my own answer. However, if @googletorp or @Azz edit their answer to include this info, I'll remove my answer and accept theirs.</sub>

The output to `:h feature-list` suggests that you should be able to use `has("win32")` and `has("macunix")`, but the latter doesn't work in the version of Vim included in OS X. (It *does*, however, work in MacVim.)

Here is what I ended up using:

```
if has("win32")
  "Windows options here
else
  if has("unix")
    let s:uname = system("uname")
    if s:uname == "Darwin\n"
      "Mac options here
    endif
  endif
endif
```

Note that `has("win32")` worked for me, even in 64 bit Vim on 64 bit Windows.

You could also use similar tests of `uname` within the `if has("unix")` block to distinguish other flavours of Unix. Just run `uname` or `uname -a` from the command-line to see what you need to compare `s:uname` with. See also `:h matchstr()` if you need to compare just a part of `uname`'s output.

Comment: For record: in vim from MSYS2 has("unix") is 1, has("win32") is 0 and has("win32unix") is 1. So use has("win32unix") to distinguish it.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look [here](http://objectmix.com/editors/149466-operating-system-checking-vimrc-files.html)

Basically, you can use either `has()`, `system()`:

```
let os = substitute(system('uname'), "\n", "", "")
if os == "SunOS"
  ..
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you're after, I don't quite understand it so I'll just link you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842078/how-do-i-detect-os-x-in-my-vimrc-file-so-certain-configurations-will-only-apply

Comment: Strange. That seems to be scraped from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842078

Comment: @Rich: All SU data is licensed under Creative Commons Attribution ShareAlike, which they seem to adhere to.

Comment: @Daniel: Interesting! Thanks for letting me know.